# monitor queries in codeigniter application

Tags: php, codeigniter, debugging

i have been working on CakePhp so far recently switched to CodeIgniter. I have a CodIgniter project which has come for performance optmization. I need to check the queries which are taking time and enhance it. I want to monitor the time taken by the queries residing in the application. I am looking for something familiar to what we have in CakePhp which we use to see each query taking how much time in debug mode. I want something like that for codeigniter. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Write the following line in the controller construct function:

```
$this->output->enable_profiler(true);
```

Comment: Did it helped you or do you need anything else?

Answer (score 2):

place the code in your construct function in the controller

```
$this->output->enable_profiler(true);
```

it will give you all the query time.